# Expo thinks sdk 36.0.0 is invalid and wont let me build:ios

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I have been working with expo and react native for an app, I am able to test on my iphone and android devices. I kept getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

I am attempting to use version 36.0.0 And it works marvelously on the devices. Now I am ready to build the app in order for me to submit it to the apple and play stores. The issue I am having is that when I do

```
expo build:ios
```

it returns the following error:

```
    Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

Request failed with status code 400

I have tried doing an expo update but I get the following message:

```
You are currently using SDK 36.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest ver
sion, 32.0.0?
```

My react native version is: 3.2.1

My Expo Version is: 3.13.2

Anyone knows how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just managed to fix it

to fix the issue:
1. npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save
2. npm install -g expo-cli --save 
3. cd ~/.expo/cache
4. rm -rf everything that is in there
5. go back to your project
6. run expo start